# How to bring the textviews of the cardview at the center in android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-jetpack, android-cardview

I have overlapped the cardviews on each other in the following manner. [image: like this]

so, as you can see in the picture my textviews are not coming at the center of the cardviews. Following are my xml layout files and the Customised overlappinglayoutmanager.kt class

fragment_to_learn_flashcards.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="@drawable/flash_tablebar"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/back_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_back" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:text="Do the practise " />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/emojiBounce"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_width="34dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/emoji" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/emptyImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        android:contentDescription="@string/empty" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        tools:listitem="@layout/recycle_view"
        app:layout_goneMarginTop="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/emptyImage"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

recycle_view.xml

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="500dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/card_border"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    app:cardElevation="4dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textLeft"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Swipe left"
                android:textColor="#00e676"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textRight"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Swipe right"
                android:textColor="#d32f2f"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/word1"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="#607d8b" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/word2"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#607d8b"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

OverlappingLayoutManager.kt

```
package com.example.visuallithuanian.custom

import android.content.Context
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.LayoutParams
import com.example.visuallithuanian.R


class OverlappingLayoutManager(context: Context) : RecyclerView.LayoutManager() {
    private val horizontalOverlap =
        context.resources.getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.card_horizontal_overlap)
    private val verticalOverlap =
        context.resources.getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.card_vertical_overlap)
    private val tiltAngle = 2f // Adjust the tilt angle as needed

    override fun generateDefaultLayoutParams(): RecyclerView.LayoutParams {
        return RecyclerView.LayoutParams(
            RecyclerView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RecyclerView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        )
    }

    override fun onLayoutChildren(recycler: RecyclerView.Recycler?, state: RecyclerView.State?) {
        if (itemCount == 0) {
            removeAndRecycleAllViews(recycler!!)
            return
        }

        detachAndScrapAttachedViews(recycler!!)

        val leftTilt = tiltAngle
        val rightTilt = -tiltAngle
        var currentTilt = leftTilt

        for (position in 0 until itemCount) {
            val view = recycler.getViewForPosition(position)
            addView(view)
            measureChildWithMargins(view, 0, 0)
            val width = getDecoratedMeasuredWidth(view)
            val height = getDecoratedMeasuredHeight(view)

            val centerX = width / 2f
            val centerY = height / 2f

            layoutDecoratedWithMargins(
                view,
                (centerX - (width / 2)).toInt(),
                (centerY - (height / 2)).toInt(),
                (centerX + (width / 2)).toInt(),
                (centerY + (height / 2)).toInt()
            )

            val childViewGroup = view.findViewById<ViewGroup>(R.id.card_view)
            childViewGroup.rotation = currentTilt

            currentTilt = if (currentTilt == leftTilt) rightTilt else leftTilt
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which TextView component you want to set it in center of cardview?

Comment: The ones ,that are not hidden from recycler_view.xml layout file

Comment: You can use RelativeLayout/ConstraintLayout instead of LinearLayout in recycler_view.xml file.